# Cloudant DB query in Node-RED function

Tags: cloudant, node-red

I want to load my tweets from the Cloudant DB by ascending order. I thought using sort: "tweet.id" would work but no.

```
msg.payload = {
    "query": "*:*",
    limit: 6,
    sort: "tweet.id",
};
return msg;
```

Node-RED flow:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work by creating a new Cloudant Query index in the Cloudant dashboard:

```
{
  "index": {
    "fields": [ "tweet.timestamp_ms" ]
  },
  "type": "json"
}
```

to index the `tweet.timestamp_ms` field. This can then be queried to return the data in timestamp order:

```
{
  "selector": {
    "_id": {
      "$gt": 0
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "tweet.timestamp_ms": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I guess this is correct if you have b bulk of stored tweets and you want to load them in ascending order. I want to press the refresh button in my browser and always load the 6 newest tweets. There is an [example](https://nodered.org/) in Node-RED but for mongoDB. I want to do the same with Cloudant.

Comment: How can one use the cloudant "query" in Node Red?  From what I've read, the only thing available in NR is using a search index.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this issue by adding the type of the variable.

What I was trying to do is to get all the documents with id=1 and then sort them by the attribute "nombre" which is a string.

My search index is:

```
function (doc) {
   index("id", doc.id, {"store": true});
   index("nombre", doc.nombre, {"store": true});
}
```

And the payload in Node-red:
[image]